# Can a long async-await chain cause big memory consumption? (theoretically)

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Looking at this code:

```
public async Task<T> ConsumeAsync()
    {
          await a();
          await b();
          await c();
          await d();
          //..
    }
```

Let's say that `a,b,c,d` also have nested async awaits (and so on)

Async/await POV - for each `await` , there is a state machine being kept.

**Question (theoretical):**

As each state machine is kept in memory, could this cause big memory consumption?
*It might be a vague question to ask, but if there are many states, it seems inevitable not to wonder about the sizes of state machines being kept.*

Comment: Note that if they complete synchronously (which does happen, more than you'd think) there is no allocation - the state machine is a struct and is only boxed when preparing to schedule a continuation. And... either way, it is pretty small.

Comment: @MarcGravell they will only be synchronously , if task has already finished by the time `await` gets there. No ?

Comment: @Marc Gravell are you sure it's a struct? [Here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAbgLAChYMQVjejKAJmwHYMBvDOGhAZmwDYEAOBZgYQHsA7AZwCuAWwCmAQT4BPHgGMAFAEpqtKulrqEATjgBDRfg20o2gEb7lh43HkKDhrXGDm1tAL4W4ABwBOASwBuOgAuIkys7LqKcAC8AHwOUIwAdAAiIgA2OpJyiDAwth4+AcGhSMxQbIlwZgox8VaJqRlZOXkFLjRFgSFhFRE2dQnJaZnZufl2nX7dpYjllcxOtXFDTaOtExju6EA==) it decompiles to a sealed class that implements `IAsyncStateMachine`.

Comment: "*for each await , there is a state machine being kept.*" -- not quite. For each method containing `awaits`, a state machine is kept. So there's a single state machine for your entire `async` method, not one for each `await` statement.

Comment: @canton7 Are you sure ? on each `await` , the FW has to "remember" the environment to get back to. Can you prove it ?

Comment: Very sure. Just decompile some code using awaits: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEAMACFBGA3AWACh0tsBWA4gZiwCYMBhDAbyI3axpQA4sA2ADwBLAHYwAfBgCyACgCULNh2WiYGIRgC8GNJWUqMAam0oAnBgAqAC1EBzeXv3sNxrOet2HSpy5PubIvZyjk4oAOzqIRgAvt4YcShcgqqSHoHyWpIofAB0AGIIAPZgAEpwUACuADYwMtjBcUTRQA . The state machine captures the entire state of the `async` method, lifting all locals into fields, and using an int+switch to represent the current point of execution in the method (one case per await statement). Each Task-returning method you call might have its own state machine, or it might not.

Comment: @canton7 TIL. interesting. I'd be happy if you can answer with a answer since my assumption is basically wrong.

Comment: @MarcGravell according to [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAbgLAChYMQVjejKAJmwHYMBvDOGhAZmwDYEAOBZgYQHsA7AZwCuAWwCmAQT4BPHgGMAFAEpqtKulrqEATjgBDRfg20o2gEb7lh43HkKDhrXGDm1tAL4W4ABwBOASwBuOgAuIkys7LqKcAC8AHwOUIwAdAAiIgA2OpJyiDAwth4+AcGhSMxQbIlwZgox8VaJqRlZOXkFLjRFgSFhFRE2dQnJaZnZufl2nX7dpYjllcxOtXFDTaOtExju6EA==), the state machines are implemented as structs in **Release** builds, and as sealed classes in **Debug** builds. I wonder what happens in **Custom** build configurations!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias almost certainly depends on the +optimize flag. Frankly, I'm only ever interested in the optimized build anyway...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Async/await POV - for each await , there is a state machine being kept.

Not true. The compiler generates a state machine for each `async` method. Locals in the method are lifted into fields on the state machine. The body of the method is (basically) broken into a `switch` statement, with each `case` corresponding to part of the method between `await` statements. An `int` is used to keep track of which bit of the method has been executed (i.e. which `case` should be executed next).

Your methods `a()`, `b()`, etc, might have their own state machines, or they might not (depending on whether they're marked `async` or not). Even if they do, in your example only one of those state machines will be instantiated at a time.

SharpLab is a great resource for exploring this stuff. [Example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEAMACFBGA3AWACh0tsBWA4gZiwCYMBhDAbyI3axpQA4sA2ADwBLAHYwAfBgCyACgCULNh2WiYGIRgC8GNJWUqMAam0oAnBgAqAC1EBzeXv3sNxrOet2HSpy5PubIvZyjk4oAOzqIRgAvt4YcShcgqqSHoHyWpIofAB0AGIIAPZgAEpwUACuADYwMtjBcUTRQA).

Comment: Not true. Each time an await command is executed, a new instance of the state machine class is created.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Please provide some evidence for that claim. The state machine is a struct, and it's boxed on the *first* await [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs,546), then the box is cached for subsequent awaits.

Comment: Look at [this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAbgLAChYMQVjejKAJmwHYMBvDOGhAZmwDYEAOBZgYQHsA7AZwCuAWwCmAQT4BPHgGMAFAEpqtKulrqEATjgBDRfg20o2gEb7lh43HkKDhrXGDm1tAL4W4ABwBOASwBuOgAuIkys7LqKcAC8AHwOUIwAdAAiIgA2OpJyiDAwth4+AcGhSMxQbIlwZgox8VaJqRlZOXkFLjRFgSFhFRE2dQnJaZnZufl2nX7dpYjllcxOtXFDTaOtExju6EA==) example.
The command `await a();` is compiled as `awaiter4 = a().GetAwaiter();` Calling method `a()` causes this command to execute `<a>d__1 stateMachine = new <a>d__1();`

Comment: @TheodorZoulias `<a>d__1` is the state machine for the `a()` method, *not* for the `ConsumeAsync` method. See my 2nd paragraph starting "*Your methods a(), b(), etc, might have their own state machines, or they might not*", and indeed my 2nd sentence "*The compiler generates a state machine for each async method.*". I asserted that the state machine for the `ConsumeAsync` method is only instantiated once. I also said that only one of the state machines for `a()`, `b()`, etc would be instantiated at a time. I'm basically repeating my answer back to you in this comment: please re-read my answer.

Comment: The OP wrote *«Let's say that a,b,c,d also have nested async awaits»*, which means that in his hypothetical scenario these methods **do** have their one state machines. Now, I misinterpreted your answer and thought that you said something you didn't said: That all awaits of a method are served by a single instance of the method's state machine. This is not true, but you didn't said that. Sorry for being a hasty reader. Please make an edit to your answer so I can revoke my downvote.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias What edit specifically do you want me to make? Your last comment only says that you didn't read my answer properly.

Comment: Make a trivial edit so I can change my vote. I am not allowed to do it otherwise: ([screenshot](http://prntscr.com/neytwf))

Comment: Aha, understood!

Comment: @canton7 Just let me make things in my head clearer ( after all comments). Theodor's last line in his last comment isn't right :   [_thought that you said something you didn't said: That all awaits of a method are served by a single instance of the method's state machine. This is not true_] - that line **isn't** true. According to your answer , all awaits of a method ARE BEING SERVED from a single state machine. - Am I right ?

Comment: 1) Each `async` method gets a single state machine, 2) That state machine is instantiated each time the method is called, 3) Different methods have different state machines. An `async` method's state machine services the *entire* method. No method has more than one state machine.

Answer (score 8):

> As each state machine is kept in memory , could this cause big memory consumption ?

Very unlikely. Each state machine will occupy a few dozen bytes, at the outside.

So it will only matter when you have very many of them. Nesting isn't really going to cause that, but executing the members of a `Task[]` might.

But that is not really new or different form any other resource type.

Answer (score 3):

There is an additional cost, but it is relatively slim.

Additional costs compared to regular function:

- A class for the state machine
- instance of this class
- one int for the stage of execution
- AsyncTaskMethodBuilder instance

Additionally, local variables of the function will be transformed into fields of the state machine. This moves some memory from a stack to the heap.

I recommend decompiling some simple async function, to see the generated state machine and have an intuition what to expect.

There are some online tools to do this as well (like sharplab.io)
See [results of decompilation of a trivial async function](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAVgNwFgBQWoGYEBMCiA7HAN5ZzUL5QAcCAbADwBGA9hwDYB8cAEQ4BlDgFsApgBcAFgEsAdgHMAFAEoqNSphq6EZKQCcArhIw6aAX03UbtBABY4AVQDOEoaMmzFqtRTtdT3FpeWV1ADoAdQBDOSl1c11rTEsgA==)

Comment: Decompiling async function will not expose the amount of memory is taken .

Comment: It will allow to see what variables are generated for the state machine and have an intuition on the overhead. I agree that you won't have a precise answer in bytes